# How did Walter White poison that character?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

I've seen Breaking Bad complete series 2-3 times, but I never found out how Walter White was able to poison Brock.

I mean did he himself directly feed the Valley of the Lilly berries to Brock or did he let Saul do the work? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Not everything needs to be shown, otherwise there's no suspense.

[However:](https://emiliajordan.com/2012/07/31/breaking-bad-how-walter-white-poisoned-brock-and-what-happened-to-the-ricin-cigarette/)

> At the 2013 Comic-Con **Vince Gilligan explained exactly how he and the
>   writers imagined Walt got the poison to Brock**, and it wasn’t, as I had
>   thought, through Saul. Instead **they pictured Walt as the “Evil Juice
>   Box Man” going into Brock’s school and giving him a juice box that had
>   juice from the poison berries.**
>
> And if you’ll look closely at episode
>   413 “Face Off” (thanks to Greg below for pointing this out), when Walt
>   busts into Saul’s office, Francesca is shredding school schedules.
>   It’s a big spreadsheet of classes and times but there are notes on the
>   side that seem to be one student’s personal schedule, most likely
>   Brock’s. So, kudos to the writers on including that little detail, and
>   again to Greg for noticing that what’s was being shredded.

Comment: Thanks bcdotweb, I agree that not everything needs to be shown. I got the answer for what I was looking.

Comment: Also, showing viewers a complete and realistic method for poisoning kids runs more risk of giving people truly stupid ideas than it's worth.