# Does the little boy Brock know who poisoned him?

Tags: breaking-bad

During **Breaking Bad** Walt poisoned the little boy Brock using Lily Of The Valley.

But while [it's not clarified how and when](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/73867/49) he did that, I was particularly wondering about Brock's behaviour around Mr. White. It was a bit odd after he comes back from the hospital. Does he know that Walt poisoned him?

Is there a clue in any of the episodes about it that I might have missed.

Comment: As stated on the accepted answer in the question you linked, *Not everything needs to be shown, otherwise there's no suspense*.

Answer (score 2):

The reason Brock is odd around Walt is that he's only seen him twice and doesn't know him at all. I remember that when the first time Brock has seen Jesse, he was very quiet around him too. But Brock definitely knew something about poison, when Walt tries to make small talk, Brock doesn't seem to be too enthusiastic about interacting with him. But he instantly got along with Jesse. Brock is only a kid, and he has no apparent reason to not like Walt unless he knows something, right?

Comment: Answers shouldn't begin with "maybe" - if you are unsure, find sources to confirm, if these are only speculations, then they are not a legible answer, only a comment.

Comment: Jesse is consistently portrayed as good with children and caring for them. He essentially signed his own death warrant avenging the kid that was forced to work for the dealers, he sympathized with and cared for the child whose deadbeat parents stole the ATM, he connects with Brock (and Walt correctly identifies he's basically do anything for Brock), and he has a lot of hangups on how his parents failed him (by treating him as an inevitable failure). Brock comparatively getting along better with Jesse than Walt speak to Jesse's character more than it does Walt's.